# How to upgrade Individual Developer Account to a Company Account?

Tags: app-store-connect, developer-program

I have an Individual Developer Account of $99 and now I want upgrade my account to a Company Account. What is the process of upgrading?

I have some running apps on the App Store with my individual account, which are showing my name under the app name.

I want it to show my company name under my app name. Is this possible after the upgrade? Can it show my company name everywhere, i.e. in iTunes Connect, Member Center etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best manner to accomplish this is to contact Apple Developer Program Support directly.

You can find their phone number and initiate a support ticket from this web page:

- https://developer.apple.com/contact/

I have found them to be expert at getting you the information you need to effect a smooth and orderly transition and help you from registering incorrectly or having any assets trapped in limbo if you make the transition incorrectly.

Comment: Hey thank you for your response!!! I contact to apple support. but for doing so thay want me to founder or cofounder of company but i am employee of my company that's the problam

Comment: Have the company appoint you as legally responsible for this activity or generally responsible to enter into contracts on behalf of the company. You can be sure the founder of Nike didn't need an iTunes Connect account for them to put apps on the store.

Answer (score 5):

Apple now provides an "Individual to Organization Membership Update" [form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/?entityType=individual&requestType=migrateAccount) to convert a personal account to a business account.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you must have a D-U-N-S number from D&B Inc. This is a number unique to your business entity that serves as a way for Apple (and other organizations) to identify your business.

Getting a new D-U-N-S number can take 30-45 days for normal registration via D&B's site but you can speed up this process for an extra fee if you register via this [link](https://fedgov.dnb.com/webform/pages/CCRSearch.jsp), it only takes 5-7 business days.

However, if you already have a legal entity for your business, you may already have this number and not know it. This may not work for brand-new legal entities, but you can search the [D&B Business Directory](https://www.dnb.com/business-directory.html) for your entities legal name and request to receive an email with your DUNS number for free. You can also search your company/organization name via [Apple D-U-N-S Number Lookup site](https://developer.apple.com/enroll/duns-lookup/#!/search) and (if needed) request a D-U-N-S number for it.

Once you get the D-U-N-S number, you can use it to fill out Apple's [Individual to Organization Membership Update form](https://developer.apple.com/contact/submit/?entityType=individual&requestType=migrateAccount) to request that your individual account be changed to a company/organization account. This is different from the "Enterprise" tier, which costs more money and is intended for businesses that need to privately distribute apps outside of the App Store.